# jquery click different div and change color and reset the other div color

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I try that when change color in div with click over there, and the other links reset his color to original if until click over this other divs

[I have test for see this, here](https://jsfiddle.net/8x5bgh3a/2/)

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:pink;" onclick="$(this).css('background-color','green');">Number 1</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:blue;" onclick="$(this).css('background-color','green');">Number 2</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:orange;" onclick="$(this).css('background-color','green');">Number 3</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:brown;" onclick="$(this).css('background-color','green');">Number 4</div>
```

If you can see the test link, when i do click change each div to color green, the idea it´s in each click only change color of div i do click, and reset color to original background color the other divs

I don´t know i can do this, if you can help me perfect, thank´s, regards

Answer (score 4):

One option is adding a class with green background(In this example the class is `.greenClass`). When clicked, remove the class `.greenClass` on all `.content` and only add the class on the clicked element.

```js
$(".content").click(function() {
  $(".content").removeClass('greenClass');
  $(this).addClass('greenClass');
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.greenClass {
  background-color: green!IMPORTANT;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:pink;">Number 1</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:blue;">Number 2</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:orange;">Number 3</div>
<div class="content n1" style="background-color:brown;">Number 4</div>
```